# hex or rgb color theme switch

Tags: javascript, colors, hex, rgb

css themes can be defined in `root` variables, by changing the `root theme css file`, we can plugin different color schemas, for example:

> blue theme

```css
:root {
    --delay: 0s;
    --bg-body: rgb(14, 14, 34);
    --bg-wrapper: #0e0e23;
    --bg-header: radial-gradient(circle, #141834 0%, #13162f 100%); 
    --bg-header-link: #11132c;
    --border-header: #4255d4;
    --border-header-hover: #28327a;
    --bg-user-box: #15193c;
    --bg-user-box-hover: #222757; 
    --bg-card: radial-gradient(circle, #1a2049 0%, #13162f 100%);
    --bg-destination: linear-gradient(45deg, #1a1d3a 0%, #212752 100%);
    --bg-cards-header: #10122b;
    --bg-cards-header-date-svg: #14183c;
    --bg-table-status-svg: #142940;
    --bg-table-row-odd: rgb(19, 23, 46);
    --bg-table-row-even: rgb(27, 32, 68);
}
```

I want to quickly generate a red schema from this blue template. I was inspired by the **vs code color picker**

[image: vscode]

the right vertical color stripe allows user to click on a certain **percentage** and switch to another color schema without changing luminosity, this is very convenient.

However, I need to

1. copy the root template
2. remember where red is about located
3. change each one manually

therefore, I started a web application that **apply regex to extract hex decimal or RGB values, and apply algorithm on all of them**

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
const preview = document.querySelector('#preview');
const inputH = document.querySelector('#h');
const inputV = document.querySelector('#v');

function hexToRgb (hex) {
  var shorthandRegex = /^#?([a-f\d])([a-f\d])([a-f\d])$/i;
  hex = hex.replace(shorthandRegex, function (m, r, g, b) {
return r + r + g + g + b + b;
  });

  var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
  return result ? 'rgb(' + [
parseInt(result[1], 16),
parseInt(result[2], 16),
parseInt(result[3], 16)
  ].join(',') + ')' : hex;
}

function rgbNum(st){
  let s = st.slice(4, -1);
  let r = s.split(',').map(t=>parseInt(t.trim()));
  return r;
}

function rgbH(rgb, h){

}

function rgbV(rgb, v){

}

button.onclick = () => {
  textarea.value = textarea.value.replaceAll(/rgb\(.*\)/g, rgb => {
rgb = rgbNum(rgb);
return rgbV(rgbH(rgb, inputH.value), inputV.value); 
  }).replaceAll(/#(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{3}){1,2}/g, hex => {
let rgb = hexToRgb(hex);
rgb = rgbNum(rgb);
return rgbV(rgbH(rgb, inputH.value), inputV.value); 
  });
}
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.button{
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: lightblue;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover{
  color: #fff;
}

#wrapper{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

#wrapper #header{
  height: 8%;
  width: 95%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background: #ddd;
}

#wrapper #editor{
  width: 93%;
  height: 47%;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#wrapper #preview{
  width: 95%;
  height: 39%;
  border: 1px solid;
}

input[type=text], 
input[type=number]{
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
<label>H<input type="number" id="h" /></label>
<label>V<input type="number" id="v" /></label>
<button type="button" class="button">go</button>
  </div>
<textarea autocomplete="off" name="editor" id="editor" cols="30" rows="10">
:root {
  --delay: 0s;
  --bg-body: rgb(14, 14, 34);
  --bg-wrapper: #0e0e23;
  --color-left-hover: #4255d4;
  --bg-header: radial-gradient(circle, #141834 0%, #13162f 100%); 
  --shadow-header: #0e0e23; 
  --bg-header-link: #11132c;
  --border-header: #4255d4;
  --border-header-hover: #28327a;
  --bg-user-box: #15193c;
  --bg-user-box-hover: #222757; 
  --bg-card: radial-gradient(circle, #1a2049 0%, #13162f 100%);
  --bg-destination: linear-gradient(45deg, #1a1d3a 0%, #212752 100%);
  --bg-cards-header: #10122b;
  --bg-cards-header-date-svg: #14183c;
  --bg-table-status-svg: #142940;
  --bg-table-row-odd: rgb(19, 23, 46);
  --bg-table-row-even: rgb(27, 32, 68);
  --bg-user-info-nav-odd: rgb(31, 35, 82);
  --bg-user-info-nav-even: rgb(40, 45, 107);
  --bg-user-info-nav-hover: rgb(18, 22, 63);
  --any: #7a474a;
}
</textarea>
  <div id="preview"></div>
</div>
```

just ignore the `rgbH` and let it return the `rgb` value.

> by editing `rgbV` function, which input a `V` **percentage** value from 0 to 100, I want to jump to the corresponding position of the **right color picker stripe on vscode**

---

I understand this is sophisticated. sorry if I get you confused. But if you have any colour algorithms for suggestion, I will be more than welcomed.

[here is a CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/MessizQin/pen/RwjMoEE)

Comment: I'd recommend you use `HSL` model instead of `RGB`. As you'd already know, `H` (hue) represents a color dimension in 360º angle, `S` its saturation, and `L` lightness—which makes it much more intuitive to reason about a specific color value and modify it. E.g., if you want to keep the same saturation and lightness but in different hue, change `H` value. Want to keep the same hue and saturation but darker? Change `L`.  (See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV )

Comment: @BumhanYu, man this is purely awesome, saved my day.

Comment: Glad it helped. `HSL` (or `HSB` with nuanced differences) comes in very handy when building themes with predictable variants. Should you need to convert between color models or/and calculate contrast ratio, `color.js` is very convenient and powerful (https://www.npmjs.com/package/color )